# Center List in side a div

Tags: css, list, icons, center

I'm trying to center my list with images inside a div. This is what I'm getting (icons way too small and not centered).

[image: Icons to small and wont center]

this is the css ive got and the html

```
       <div id="social">

                <ul>
                    <li><img src="img/footertwitter.png" alt="placeholder+image"></li>
                    <li><img src="img/footerfacebook.png" alt="placeholder+image"></li>
                    <li><img src="img/footeremail.png" alt="placeholder+image"></li>
                </ul>

            </div>


        #social {
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
width: 90%;
max-width: 1140px;
position: relative;
  }

    #social ul {
/*margin: 0 0 3em 0!important;*/
padding: 0!important;

}

  #social ul li {
list-style-type: none;
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 1.5em;
margin-right: 1.5em;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your rule for the `ul` consider setting the display property to block and the margins to auto.   If I understand correctly what you're trying to accomplish, that should center things for you while retaining the margins you assigned.

The updated CSS would look like:

```
#social 
{
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1140px;
  position: relative;
}

#social ul 
{
  padding: 0;
  margin:auto;
  display: block;
}

#social ul li 
{
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 1.5em;
  margin-right: 1.5em;
}
```

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ag82b/) shows the changes in action.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can simply increase the icon size according to your need:

   ## social ul li img {

   ```
   width:50px; 
   height:50px;
   ```

   }
2. Give a fixed width to ul and then put it in the center using the following code:

   ## social ul {

   ```
   width:300px; /*Example*/
   display:block;
   margin:0 auto;
   ```

   }