# Centering navigation bar won't work

Tags: html, css, replace, navigation, center

I have made a navigation bar and I am trying to make it centered to fit all screens, with position absolute and then use left: 50%; and then place it by margin-left: 100px; to get it exactly where I want it. I have done this to all my buttons and it worked, but when I try doing it on my navigation bar, it moves the whole bar to the middle and when I then move it, it won't work.

html code:

```
<div id="navBarTop">
        <ul>
                <li><a href="test.html">test</a></li>
                <li><a href="test.html">test</a></li>
                <li><a href="test.html">test</a></li>
                <li><a href="test.html">test</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

css code as it is normally:

```
 #navBarTop {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #FFB700;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4c4c4c;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

#navBarTop ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0; 
    margin-left: 350px;
}

#navBarTop li {
    float: left; 
}

#navBarTop li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Arial";
    color: #4c4c4c;
    border-right: 1px solid #4c4c4c; 
}

#navBarTop li:first-child a {
    border-left: 1px solid #4c4c4c; 
}

#navBarTop li a:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff; 
}
```

css when I am trying to make it centered(doesn't work):

```
#navBarTop {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #FFB700;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4c4c4c;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
}

#navBarTop ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0; 
    margin-left: 350px;
}

#navBarTop li {
    float: left; 
}

#navBarTop li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Arial";
    color: #4c4c4c;
    border-right: 1px solid #4c4c4c; 
}

#navBarTop li:first-child a {
    border-left: 1px solid #4c4c4c; 
}

#navBarTop li a:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff; 
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Center List in side a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670713/center-list-in-side-a-div)

Comment: If you don't plan on having nested navigation, why not use the <nav></nav> tags to contain your links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're trying too hard.

```css
#navBarTop {
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #FFB700;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4c4c4c;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
#navBarTop ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
#navBarTop li {
    display: inline-block;
}
#navBarTop li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:"Arial";
    color: #4c4c4c;
    border-right: 1px solid #4c4c4c;
}
#navBarTop li:first-child a {
    border-left: 1px solid #4c4c4c;
}
#navBarTop li a:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div id="navBarTop">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="test.html">test</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="test.html">test</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="test.html">test</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="test.html">test</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```